# How do I stop jQuery TourBus from creating two instances on click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using [jQuery Tourbus](https://ryanfunduk.com/jquery-tourbus/) to guide a user through my website. I want it to show up on loading the window the first time someone visits but after that it shouldn't load unless the user clicks on the information icon.

To make sure it auto loads only when the user vists the first time, I did this -

```
<?php
    if($tourbus_verify==0) {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load( function() {
    var tour = $('#my-tour-id').tourbus( {} );
    tour.trigger('depart.tourbus');
} );
</script>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Upon loading the page, I have a method that enters the value `1` into the database. So, if a user visits for the first time, `$tourbus_verify` will be `0`, so the tour loads when the page loads. If the user has already visited the page before, the `$tourbus_verify` will be `1` so it won't auto load.

The tour it loads is as follows -

```
<ol class='tourbus-legs' id='my-tour-id'>

  <li data-orientation='centered' data-width='400'>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-next'>Next</a>
  </li>

  <li data-el='#stuff' data-orientation='top' data-width='400'>
    <p>That's awesome</p>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-prev'>Previous</a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-next'>Next</a>
  </li>

  <li data-el='#tourbus-restart' data-orientation='left' data-width='400'>
    <p>Bye</p>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-stop'>End!</a>
  </li>

</ol>
```

Everything works well so far. Now, I have an icon which upon clicking loads the tour -

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <span style="cursor: pointer;" id="tourbus-restart">
      <i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

And at the end of the page, I have -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#tourbus-restart").click(function(){
    var tourclick = $('#my-tour-id1').tourbus( {} );
    tourclick.trigger('depart.tourbus');
});
</script>
```

This loads the same tour as before but with a different ID -

```
<ol class='tourbus-legs' id='my-tour-id1'>

      <li data-orientation='centered' data-width='400'>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-next'>Next</a>
      </li>

      <li data-el='#stuff' data-orientation='top' data-width='400'>
        <p>That's awesome</p>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-prev'>Previous</a>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-next'>Next</a>
      </li>

      <li data-el='#tourbus-restart' data-orientation='left' data-width='400'>
        <p>Bye</p>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-stop'>End!</a>
      </li>

    </ol>
```

For some reason, this works well once, but fires an additional instance of the tour the second time, so I end up running two tours at the same time as shown in the image below -

[image]

So, I have to click each `Next` twice to finish the tour. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: I have never used this plugin, but I would suspect that it might be because you are initializing and re-initializing the plugin every time you click on a button. Looking at the developer's [demo code](https://ryanfunduk.com/jquery-tourbus/demo.js), he does it once outside the `click` event handler.

Comment: @Mikey That worked, thank you! I looked at the developer's demo code and changed mine to –
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var docsBus = $.tourbus( '#my-tour-id1' );

    $(document).on( 'click', '#tourbus-icon', function() {
      $('#my-tour-id1').trigger('depart.tourbus');
    });
});
</script>`
I'm fairly new to jQuery so I don't understand what the difference is here. Why was my code re-initializing the plugin? If you could post that as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it this way:

The line `$(selector).tourbus()` is to initialize the plugin and bind some functionality to the element `selector`. When you put it inside the `click` event handler, you are initializing the element only when you click. So, if you click twice, then you are initializing twice. I can only assume clicking three times would initialize the plugin three times on the element; and so forth. When you initialize again, the previous instance(s) still remain attached the element.

So, by putting the line outside the `click` event handler, you are ensuring that the plugin is initialized only once.