# How to create a backdrop using the jQuery TourBus plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is a followup question to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001228/how-do-i-stop-jquery-tourbus-from-creating-two-instances-on-click).

I'm trying to create a backdrop for the tour that guides through my website using [jQuery Tourbus](https://ryanfunduk.com/jquery-tourbus/), where it highlights the `div` that it is pointing to and dims the background. The plugin developer provides [an example](https://ryanfunduk.com/jquery-tourbus/#example-4) for this. I'm trying to implement the same but it doesn't seem to work. The tour loads as usual. but it neither creates a backdrop nor highlights the `div` it is pointing to.

This is my jQuery code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
   var tour = $('#my-tour-id').tourbus( {
      onLegStart: function( leg, bus ) {
         if( leg.rawData.highlight ) {
         leg.$target.addClass('my-tour-highlight');
         $('.my-tour-overlay').show();
      }
   },
      onLegEnd: function( leg, bus ) {
         if( leg.rawData.highlight ) {
         leg.$target.removeClass('my-tour-highlight');
         $('.my-tour-overlay').hide();
      }
   }
 });
 tour.trigger('depart.tourbus');
 console.log("load");
} );
</script>
```

CSS -

```
<style>
    .my-tour-overlay {
       display: none;
       background: #666;
       opacity: 0.5;
       z-index: 9997;
       min-height: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
   }

   .my-tour-highlight {
       background: white;
       position: relative;
       border-radius: 4px;
       box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
       z-index: 9998;
   }
</style>
```

HTML -

```
<ol class='tourbus-legs' id='my-tour-id'>
  <li data-orientation='centered' data-width='400'>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-next'>Next</a>
  </li>
  <li data-el='#stuff' data-orientation='top' data-width='400'>
    <p>That's awesome</p>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-prev'>Previous</a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-next'>Next</a>
  </li>
  <li data-el='#tourbus-restart' data-orientation='left' data-width='400'>
    <p>Bye</p>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tourbus-stop'>End!</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

As you can see, I'm following the instructions as they are. What could be going wrong? Thanks!

EDIT - Thanks to @charlietfl, I was able to create a backdrop. However, the element that is being pointed to by the tour leg is not being highlighted and instead is dimmed like the rest of the backdrop.

The changes I've made are to my HTML code. I've added `data-highlight="true"` to `<li data-el='#stuff' data-orientation='top' data-width='400'>` and also added this at the end of the ordered list for tourlegs - `<div class="my-tour-overlay" style="display: block;"></div>`

How can I highlight the element during the tour and separate it from the backdrop? Thanks!

Comment: can u provide a fiddle?

Comment: If you want help with something like this I would suggest you create a demo in a sandbox site that we can inspect with dev tools and fork the code.

Comment: What does `leg.rawData` look like? Note: I have never used this plugin and don't know where `rawData` gets set but doesn't seem to be anything shown that would indicate `highlight` in your code

Comment: @charlietfl [This is the only information](https://ryanfunduk.com/jquery-tourbus/#custom-properties) the developer has provided on `rawData`. Couldn't find anything else about it. How do you propose I create a demo? On JSFiddle as @Piyush.kapoor has suggested?

Comment: Looks like `rawdata` is created from any `data-` attributes. Try adding `data-highlight="true"` to target element. As for demo...any sandbox like jsfiddle, plunker, jsbin, codepen etc can be used

Comment: @charlietfl This was great advice, thanks a lot. I was able to get the backdrop working but it does not highlight the element that it is pointing to. I'm unable to get a sandbox demo working, probably due to the number of dependencies in my site. I will update this question with the changes I've made and hopefully can get it to work. Thanks again!